# Why does access of non existent `data.table` column using `[[]]` not give error like x[, j]

Tags: r, data.table

```
> z <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 1:5)
> z[["p"]]
NULL
> z[, c("p")]
Error in `[.data.table`(z, , c("p")) : column(s) not found: p
```

`z[["p"]]` does not give error unlike `z[, c("p")]`. I do understand the latter needs to return a `data.table` while first one returns a `vector`.  A possible reason seems to be `x[, j]` format needs to support multiple columns, and hence it throws error pointing out the issue columns, if any. Can someone confirm this ?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1169456/680068

Comment: This isn't just `data.table`, it's things that inherit `data.frame` (including `tbl_df`). `$` and `[[` are very similar, `z$p` will also return `NULL`. For whatever reason (idk), the default behavior of `[[` is to be more tolerant of not-present fields.